# How to Change JSX Attribute over time

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm working on a Threejs with React Three Fiber.
Want some help using a function that change a JSX attribute with a counter or something.
Want to change with time, as long as the user stays on the page the **intensity** attribute goes up and down. The max value for it (in this case is 1 and the min is 0)

Here is my code so far..

```js
import React from "react";

// import { random } from 'lodash';

export default () => {
  const FakeSphere = () => {
    return (
      <mesh>
        <sphereBufferGeometry args={[0.7, 30, 30]} attach="geometry" />
        <meshBasicMaterial color={0xfff1ef} attach="material" />
      </mesh>
    );
  };

  return (
    <group>
      <FakeSphere />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.3} /> // Want to change this value
      <pointLight intensity={0.7} position={[0, 5, 0]} />
    </group>
  );
};
```

Comment: I dont know how to write the function that as long times goes on the page. Changes dynamicaly the value from 0.0 to 1.0. going up slowly then coming back. With that I would be able to re-use it on a lot of other elements of my project :( pls help

Answer (score 2):

The react-three-fiber [landing page has a code demo](https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber#what-does-it-look-like) that demonstrates how to animate objects. The function is `useFrame()` and it passes an argument with a `clock` object that you can use to keep track of elapsed time. For example:

```jsx
const FakeSphere = () => {
    // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh
    const mesh = useRef();

    useFrame((t) => {
        // Here we use a sine wave to move between y: [-1, 1]
        mesh.current.position.y = Math.sin(t.clock.elapsedTime);
    });

    return (
        <mesh
            {...props}
            ref={mesh}
            /* ... */>
        </mesh>
    );
}
```

Comment: I will give a try. If nice give you correct answer, thank you

Comment: The {...props} part did not work well. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. About the useFrame and useRef i kinda get how its done

Comment: You don't need to include props if you're not using it. I was just copying the demo on the landing page. Please feel free to modify my code sample to fit your needs.